# Auto submit from email

Tags: php, forms, email, submit, reply

I don't know if there is a easier way to do this, im starting out with php, I am trying to add a link to a email letter so that once the link is pressed it opens a webpage and auto submits a form to my email address with just a reference number that was added to the link.

I have tried a few ways with php but can only get a blank email to arrive.

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: That's not really a scalable solution, have you considered inserting the data into a database?

Comment: Why add the extra step of auto submitting a form, rather than just contacting the target of the form directly? Are you requiring user input?

Comment: Yes I will probably end up doing it that way, like the subscribe and unsubscribe button on emails, I was just wondering if there was a way without creating a database

Comment: basically im looking to add a subscribe button to my emails without using a database

Comment: If you aren't using a database, how will you store who is subscribed?

Answer (score 0):

Use an id(identifier) with the link. Use the id later to track who had opened the link.

When sending email add a parameter to link ("?referer=xyx23")  and save the refere in database. When user opens the link you can track using the database the referer

Answer (score 0):

You need add link with the unique get-parameter, like: http://your-site.com?sendemail=9adb879856464.
This parameter saved in the database. If user enters the site using link from email at the server run the script, this script checks, if is the link valid. If link is valid, check is the link in the database. If this link is in the database, then send the mail using php mail-function. If you want user used link once, delete the link in the database.